# "Invalid value for 'attribute'" (of type Yes/No) when creating product programmatically

Tags: product, import, product-attribute, create-product

When creating a product programmatically using the method described [here](http://www.magentogeek.com/create-a-simple-product-magento-programmatically/), what format does the value need to be in for a Yes/No attribute type? (note: my attribute is global)

So far I have tried the following values for my Yes/No field:
0 and 1
1 and 2
'0' and '1'
'1' and '2'

So far all I am getting is the error "Invalid value for 'myAttributeName'"

I have scoured Google but somehow can't find an example of someone creating a product in this way where a Yes/No type attribute was used.

Note: I will test other values such as true false, 'Yes' 'No', and -1 0 and update question shortly.

Comment: You should be fine using `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it turns out that the values need to be formatted as:
**'Yes'** or **'No'** (including quotation marks / denoting a string)

Note:this is probably also dependant on the language being used for your store.

Comment: And this is on a default Magento product yes/no attribute or a select? BY the way, thank you for returning and answering your question

Answer (score 1):

It is dependant to the language in Backend.

If the shop is in german language for example than the value has to be **Ja** or **Nein**.